# Profile copying does not correctly copy empty age field

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-copying

I just copied my profile from SO to meta. I had not given a date of birth in SO but I had entered date for meta.

After copying [my profile in meta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431/juha-syrjala) has correct information in other fields but the age field. I was expecting that the age field would be empty because it was empty in SO.

Comment: Actually, this appears to occur for any empty field. I tested it with my location, it probably would occur likewise for the other fields. I would guess that copying only actually transfers information which is there to transfer, it won't blank out information you've entered.

Comment: I'm assuming this is by-design so you don't unexpectedly lose information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments have suggested, only fields that contain actual data will be copied. It will not blank out existing data.

Comment: this is correct -- it only copies actual data not nulls. From the user's perspective that would be a *DELETE!*