# If these two questions are related, then so are Steve Jobs and Richard Stallman

Tags: bug, status-completed, related-questions, algorithm

Exhibit A:

> ### [Profile copying does not correctly copy empty age field](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48627/profile-copying-does-not-correctly-copy-empty-age-field)
>
> I just copied my profile from SO to meta. I had not given a date of birth in SO but I had entered date for meta.
>
> After copying [my profile in meta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1431/juha-syrjala) has correct information in other fields but the age field. I was expecting that the age field would be empty because it was empty in SO.
>
> `[bug]` `[profile-copying]`

---

Exhibit B:

> ### [Why does Jeff Dislike Meta So Much?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27268/why-does-jeff-dislike-meta-so-much)
>
> [On this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/849/the-4th-in-the-trilogy) , Jeff comments: "I try to pretend meta doesn't exist".
>
> Why does Jeff hate Meta so much? As Meta's parent, doesn't this seem like bad parenting? Shouldn't Jeff love all his (web)children? Isn't he afraid Meta will grow up with a complex?
>
> `[meta-meta]` `[discussion]` `[fun]`

---

My question: Why in the name of all that is good and computable *does Exhibit B appear as the top related question on Exhibit A?*

Comment: HA HA HAHA HA HA HAA HAH AHAHA +1

Comment: The only words shared between the two questions are "does", "I", "so", "to", "meta", and "a". They don't even share "not" because one post exclusively uses contractions while the other exclusively doesn't. Wow.

Comment: Well, both contain several common words such as "meta", "the" and "and" ;)

Comment: Actually, I would have thought RMS and Jobs are exactly the same kind of person.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A uses the word "meta", so it is obviously meta-meta. That's a keyword in B, so there's a very strong connection right there.

Comment: Hmm. I didn't expect to be correct with that...

Answer (score 13):

This is easy. Clearly the system foresaw this very question that you asked. That is, those two questions are mentioned in this question, giving them a common link, and the system saw this linkage coming.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's telepathy!

Comment: telepathy is magic, but this is just science. the SO engine is merely utilizing the many-universes principle of quantum mechanics, and evaluating several possible universes to determine which one is most likely to occur. in this case, it correctly determined that the universe in which @balpha would eventually post this question was the most likely.  see, nothing magic, just simple science that any third-grader could do for a science fair project.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't considering that having a Richard Stallman open letter as a *Related question* of a Steve Jobs open letter would indeed be very correct, as even when they most likely will show diametrically opposite views and arrive to very different conclusions, this *linkage* would allow you to view the different points of view that can be had on the topic at hand.

[image]
<sub>(source: [shamusyoung.com](http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/images/freedom_control.jpg))</sub>

Having said that, I would never imply that they are both relatives. I would never do that. [They don't](http://theexperiencegalleryblog.files.wordpress.com/2009/04/jobs_woz.jpg) [even look](http://coe.berkeley.edu/forefront/fall2005/images/woz2.jpg) [the](http://kangtatang.files.wordpress.com/2008/12/press_richard_stallman.jpg) [same](http://es.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=aau5i9&s=5).

<sub>Now, why those two posts are related, I have no idea.</sub>

Comment: But Woz could pass for Stallman's brother.  I had not noticed this before.

Comment: +1 for the office reference

Comment: You could at least get the office reference correct. It should be Ricky Gervais ;-)

Comment: @Simon: it's an obviously flawed Gauss Bell. If I were to make it, I'd of course include Ricky Gervais and Steve Jobs in there.

Answer (score 2):

A clue to understanding this:

```
title
   "profile copying correctly copy empty age field"
html
   "meta"
dbtags
   "bug OR profile-copying"
```

Puzzle: what did I change to fix it? balpha is not eligible to answer as he knows the answer already :)

Comment: Mmm... disabled comparing tags and html body when determining related questions? Because `meta. I had not given a date of birth in SO but I had entered date for meta.` melted down to `meta meta` ?

Answer (score 1):

The same way this question is related to [Badges algorithm in SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38605/badges-algorithm-for-so)

Comment: eny meny miny mo....

Comment: At least they're both tagged [algorithm]