# Related Questions & Tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, related-questions

I'm not completely sure about this but seams that the tags inputed by the user are not involved for populating the "Related Questions" list.

I think it should be included because otherwise the results can be completely unrelated to the  question and actually doesn't help to find out eventually duplicated questions.

Then, I understand that now it's not involved because the tags are at the bottom of the page and inputed just at the end, but...

Comment: This is an excellent idea. Having just gained enough rep to moderate posts, anything that could be done to decrease the number of duplicate  questions is a good idea in my book.

Comment: This was the request at [Would it be feasible to tie the tags of a new question to the Related Questions list?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions-l). On a related note (haha), [enjoy some history of the Related Questions list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48629/if-these-two-questions-are-related-then-so-are-steve-jobs-and-richard-stallman).

Comment: @grace - So, the request to reduce duplicates has a duplicate, huh? Gotta love it.